# Top level directory files like readme.txt are served by apache

Tags: http-request

The content of the top-level server directory is publicly available by the web, e.g. files like example.com/readme.txt are readable.
Is it normal? How can i disable this?

(apache, ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not normal. Test if your .htaccess file is there, and looks the same as one in the fresh copy downloaded from Drupal.org - if they are different, use the stock one.

If your .htaccess file is identical to the stock one, you need to make your Apache to respect this part:

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(|~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

How exactly you should do it would be off topic here, but may be asked on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

**Note** that while default .htaccess protect most extensions you don't want served, it does not hide txt files you explicitly asked for. So just add that extension to the list, as you can see, it's pretty straightforward.

This will block txt files from all directories, except *sites/*/files*, that have separate .htaccess files, with their own rules of access (since 7.22). If you don't want to serve core's readme.txt, then you probably don't want to serve modules' readme.txt too.

Comment: That's what seemed to me. The .htaccess is here, though, and the private directory for example is properly protected,

Comment: @Dalmaz that makes it Apache or Ubuntu question. From Drupal's point of view, everything is all right.

Comment: Don't add the txt ext. to that list, it isn't what you want! You want to hide only the txt files on the root directory, not *all* txt files.

Comment: @Rotem since 7.22 *sites/sitename/files* directories has separate .htaccess fiels with their own rules of allowance and denial. And I don't see how anyone would want to serve txt files like */sites/all/modules/modulename/readme.txt* - they are exactly as bad as readme for core.

Comment: @Mołot From your last clarifications I understand that actually the fact that the README.txt file is available publicly is actually the default behavior - and actually the directive you mentioned does not say anything about .txt files.

Comment: By the way I found a fine explanation of the regex in question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676012/understanding-htaccess-filesmatch-code

Answer (score 4):

As I understood - you want to hide the txt files on the root direcroty (e.g. Changlog.txt) from prying eyes, therefore you can search Drupal.org for that question (its there..), and you'll see 3 types of solutions:
1. Leave those file as they are ( I don't like that option)
2. Just delete those files
3. Hide them using the site's .htaccess (My favorite option)

Comment: So is it the default behaviour? I'm afraid my server is misonfigured.

Comment: Read this - https://drupal.org/node/79018 , it is Drupal 6 issue, but has a lot of comments related to D7